# Multiple JQPL fetch joins fail with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, join, fetch, jpql

Using Hibernate 3.6.7 and JPA 2, I cannot have two fetch joins in one query. Entity has a self referencing field called parent. localizedTexts is an `@ElementCollection`, of Java type of Map. entity.getParent() has a @ManyToOne with EAGER loading strategy.

Here is How entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Entity extends BaseEntity {
    /* ... */

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Entity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "language")
    @Column(name = "text")
    public Map<String, String> getLocalizedTexts() {
        return localizedTexts;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

The following two queries work:

```
select e from Entity e join fetch e.parent.localizedTexts

select e from Entity e join fetch e.localizedTexts
```

But this doesn't work:

```
select e from Entity e join fetch e.localizedTexts join fetch e.parent.localizedTexts
```

Hibernate complains:
`query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=net.company.project.Entity.localizedTexts,tableName={none},tableAlias=localizedt3_,origin=null,columns={,className=null}}] [select e from net.company.project.Entity e join fetch e.localizedTexts join fetch e.parent.localizedTexts]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preload the Entities "parent" associations as well as the parent's "localizedTexts" association you should declare joins that traverse the model tree in the correct order:

```
select e from Entity e join fetch e.parent p joint fetch p.localizedTexts
```

Comment: No difference. Same exception is thrown for this query: select e from Entity e join e.parent p join fetch e.localizedTexts join fetch p.localizedTexts

Comment: If you have a OneToMany or oneTOOne association from e to parent and a onetoMany from parent to localizedTexts then the above join should work. Please post a code snipped of these beans and their associations between them

Comment: as mentioned before localizedTexts is MapKeyColumn, and there is a ManyToOne on getParent()